# How do I make a powerpoint file with apache poi that changes slides every 30 seconds?

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

Right now I generate a set of slides and when I open it as a pps it doesn't transition between slides unless I open it in microsoft's powerpoint editor (where I can add the transition) and save it. Then it transitions fine.

I think it has something to do with the slide master:
https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlideMaster.html
but I'm not sure how this is used as it says it handles the transition between slides but there are no methods indicating this.

Here is a diff of the before and after the change as after 7zip extracts it:

```
diff -ur after/docProps/core.xml after_no_timing/docProps/core.xml
--- after/docProps/core.xml 1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0400
+++ after_no_timing/docProps/core.xml   1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
-<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><dc:title>PowerPoint Presentation</dc:title><cp:lastModifiedBy>David H</cp:lastModifiedBy><cp:revision>2</cp:revision><dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2006-08-16T00:00:00Z</dcterms:created><dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-03-08T23:29:29Z</dcterms:modified></cp:coreProperties>
\ No newline at end of file
+<cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dcmitype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><dc:title>PowerPoint Presentation</dc:title><cp:lastModifiedBy>David H</cp:lastModifiedBy><cp:revision>3</cp:revision><dcterms:created xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2006-08-16T00:00:00Z</dcterms:created><dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2018-03-09T00:51:42Z</dcterms:modified></cp:coreProperties>
\ No newline at end of file
diff -ur after/ppt/slides/slide1.xml after_no_timing/ppt/slides/slide1.xml
--- after/ppt/slides/slide1.xml 1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0400
+++ after_no_timing/ppt/slides/slide1.xml   1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
-<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><p:cSld><p:spTree><p:nvGrpSpPr><p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/><p:cNvGrpSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvGrpSpPr><p:grpSpPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/><a:chOff x="0" y="0"/><a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/></a:xfrm></p:grpSpPr><p:graphicFrame><p:nvGraphicFramePr><p:cNvPr id="2" name="Table 1"/><p:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/></p:cNvGraphicFramePr><p:nvPr/></p:nvGraphicFramePr><p:xfrm><a:off x="254000" y="254000"/><a:ext cx="8255000" cy="4511040"/></p:xfrm><a:graphic><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table"><a:tbl><a:tblPr/><a:tblGrid><a:gridCol w="6985000"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}"><a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="20000"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:gridCol><a:gridCol w="1270000"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}"><a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="20001"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:gridCol></a:tblGrid><a:tr h="254000"><a:tc gridSpan="2"><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="ctr"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="3200" b="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="000000"/></a:solidFill></a:rPr><a:t>Designer file changes</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc hMerge="1"><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10000"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="254000"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" b="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:rPr><a:t>Filename</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="0163B1"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" b="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:rPr><a:t>Times Changed</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="0163B1"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10001"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>TabularPage.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>2</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10002"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>config.yaml</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>2</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10003"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>log4j-1.2.17.jar</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10004"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>commons-collections4-4.1.jar</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10005"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10006"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>MapUtilTest.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10007"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>Main.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10008"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>BulletedPage.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10009"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>eclipse_project_output.ppt</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10010"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr></a:tbl></a:graphicData></a:graphic></p:graphicFrame></p:spTree></p:cSld><p:clrMapOvr><a:masterClrMapping/></p:clrMapOvr><mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"><mc:Choice xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" Requires="p14"><p:transition spd="slow" p14:dur="2000" advClick="0" advTm="30000"/></mc:Choice><mc:Fallback><p:transition spd="slow" advClick="0" advTm="30000"/></mc:Fallback></mc:AlternateContent></p:sld>
\ No newline at end of file
+<p:sld xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><p:cSld><p:spTree><p:nvGrpSpPr><p:cNvPr id="1" name=""/><p:cNvGrpSpPr/><p:nvPr/></p:nvGrpSpPr><p:grpSpPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="0" cy="0"/><a:chOff x="0" y="0"/><a:chExt cx="0" cy="0"/></a:xfrm></p:grpSpPr><p:graphicFrame><p:nvGraphicFramePr><p:cNvPr id="2" name="Table 1"/><p:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks noGrp="1"/></p:cNvGraphicFramePr><p:nvPr/></p:nvGraphicFramePr><p:xfrm><a:off x="254000" y="254000"/><a:ext cx="8255000" cy="4511040"/></p:xfrm><a:graphic><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/table"><a:tbl><a:tblPr/><a:tblGrid><a:gridCol w="6985000"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}"><a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="20000"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:gridCol><a:gridCol w="1270000"><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{9D8B030D-6E8A-4147-A177-3AD203B41FA5}"><a16:colId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="20001"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:gridCol></a:tblGrid><a:tr h="254000"><a:tc gridSpan="2"><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="ctr"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="3200" b="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="000000"/></a:solidFill></a:rPr><a:t>Designer file changes</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc hMerge="1"><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10000"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="254000"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" b="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:rPr><a:t>Filename</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="0163B1"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US" b="1"><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:rPr><a:t>Times Changed</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="0163B1"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10001"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>TabularPage.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>2</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10002"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>config.yaml</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>2</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10003"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>log4j-1.2.17.jar</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10004"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>commons-collections4-4.1.jar</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10005"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10006"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>MapUtilTest.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10007"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>Main.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10008"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>BulletedPage.java</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="FFFFFF"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10009"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr><a:tr h="317500"><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>eclipse_project_output.ppt</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:tc><a:txBody><a:bodyPr/><a:lstStyle/><a:p><a:pPr algn="l"/><a:r><a:rPr lang="en-US"/><a:t>1</a:t></a:r><a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100"/></a:p></a:txBody><a:tcPr><a:lnL><a:noFill/></a:lnL><a:lnR><a:noFill/></a:lnR><a:lnT><a:noFill/></a:lnT><a:lnB><a:noFill/></a:lnB><a:solidFill><a:srgbClr val="1085C6"/></a:solidFill></a:tcPr></a:tc><a:extLst><a:ext uri="{0D108BD9-81ED-4DB2-BD59-A6C34878D82A}"><a16:rowId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" val="10010"/></a:ext></a:extLst></a:tr></a:tbl></a:graphicData></a:graphic></p:graphicFrame></p:spTree></p:cSld><p:clrMapOvr><a:masterClrMapping/></p:clrMapOvr><mc:AlternateContent xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"><mc:Choice xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" Requires="p14"><p:transition spd="slow" p14:dur="2000" advClick="0"/></mc:Choice><mc:Fallback><p:transition spd="slow" advClick="0"/></mc:Fallback></mc:AlternateContent></p:sld>
\ No newline at end of file
diff -ur after/ppt/viewProps.xml after_no_timing/ppt/viewProps.xml
--- after/ppt/viewProps.xml 1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0400
+++ after_no_timing/ppt/viewProps.xml   1980-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 -0400
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
-<p:viewPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main" lastView="sldThumbnailView"><p:normalViewPr><p:restoredLeft sz="15620" autoAdjust="0"/><p:restoredTop sz="94622" autoAdjust="0"/></p:normalViewPr><p:slideViewPr><p:cSldViewPr><p:cViewPr varScale="1"><p:scale><a:sx n="109" d="100"/><a:sy n="109" d="100"/></p:scale><p:origin x="1068" y="114"/></p:cViewPr><p:guideLst><p:guide orient="horz" pos="2160"/><p:guide pos="2880"/></p:guideLst></p:cSldViewPr></p:slideViewPr><p:outlineViewPr><p:cViewPr><p:scale><a:sx n="33" d="100"/><a:sy n="33" d="100"/></p:scale><p:origin x="0" y="0"/></p:cViewPr></p:outlineViewPr><p:notesTextViewPr><p:cViewPr><p:scale><a:sx n="100" d="100"/><a:sy n="100" d="100"/></p:scale><p:origin x="0" y="0"/></p:cViewPr></p:notesTextViewPr><p:gridSpacing cx="76200" cy="76200"/></p:viewPr>
\ No newline at end of file
+<p:viewPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:p="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main"><p:normalViewPr><p:restoredLeft sz="15620" autoAdjust="0"/><p:restoredTop sz="94622" autoAdjust="0"/></p:normalViewPr><p:slideViewPr><p:cSldViewPr><p:cViewPr varScale="1"><p:scale><a:sx n="109" d="100"/><a:sy n="109" d="100"/></p:scale><p:origin x="1068" y="114"/></p:cViewPr><p:guideLst><p:guide orient="horz" pos="2160"/><p:guide pos="2880"/></p:guideLst></p:cSldViewPr></p:slideViewPr><p:outlineViewPr><p:cViewPr><p:scale><a:sx n="33" d="100"/><a:sy n="33" d="100"/></p:scale><p:origin x="0" y="0"/></p:cViewPr></p:outlineViewPr><p:notesTextViewPr><p:cViewPr><p:scale><a:sx n="100" d="100"/><a:sy n="100" d="100"/></p:scale><p:origin x="0" y="0"/></p:cViewPr></p:notesTextViewPr><p:gridSpacing cx="76200" cy="76200"/></p:viewPr>
\ No newline at end of file
```

It looks like I want `<p:transition spd="slow" advClick="0" advTm="30000"/>`
instead of `<p:transition spd="slow" advClick="0"/>`, but how do I use POI's XMLObject to get the changes into the powerpoint?

Comment: So when you unzip the before- and after-file, what's the difference?

Comment: It's hard to tell because it looks like the xml inside of the slidemaster class is obfuscated.

Comment: In this case you need to trial-and-error adapting the before file to the state afterwards in small steps. Eventually you find out what needs to be changed. After you've added the element which made it working, you need try to revert the elements stepwise which you've added before to get a reasonable small modification set. what do you mean by obfuscated? the slide master has a different xml layout than normal slides.

Comment: The problem though is I don't know how to change properties through poi at all.

Comment: If you know which xml part to change, than it's easy to access and modify it via the getXmlObject() method, but the hard part is the trial-and-error, which you could do with most text editors and a zip tool, i.e. add a piece of xml structure of your after file to the before file, see if it still can be opened and has the wanted effect, repeat ...

Comment: I think I found the value that I need to add to the xmlobject, but how do I add it?

Comment: [XSLFSlide.getXmlObject](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFSlide.html#getXmlObject--) -> [CTSlide](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/presentationml/x2006/main/CTSlide.java) -> `getTransition()` -> [CTSlideTransition](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/presentationml/x2006/main/CTSlideTransition.java#CTSlideTransition) -> `setAdvTm(long advTm)`.

Comment: I can't import that class, "CTSlideTransition".

Comment: Turns out I was missing the oomxml-schemas library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the library that contains the xml schemas for the slides (ooxml-schema.jar) after that I needed to call:

```
XSLFSlide.getXmlObject.getTransition().setAdvTm(long advTm)
```